# get panel at specific positions in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

ive got for example 25 panels that are formed like a grid (5 rows, 5 columns),
if i click at one of those i want to get e.g. the panel above too.
at first i named the panels like their positions e.g. PanelX1Y1, PanelX1Y2 ...
then i took the coords out of the name and created the new coords...
and after i got the new name, i used a foreach loop to go through all the items and get that one with the right name.

ive already tried it with the winforms positions so i took the positions of the clicked one addet e.g. 25 pixels and lopped through all the items in form and checked them via their location.

But i dont want to looped through all the items ...
how can i get the item if i know its name whitout to loop through all items and check for their names..

can i use this:
this.Controls["name"];

okay my grid:
p11 p12 p13
p21 p22 p23
p31 p32 p33

if i click on p31 i want to change something at p31 and p21 so i need the object p21

Comment: It's not very clear what you're after ... can you provide an example scenario ? Not an explanation, mind you, but something like "ok, I've got this. If I do this and that, it should do this and that, but does this and that instead, this is the relevant code involved"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer you question, you can use the `Find()` method of the `ControlCollection` class. e.g.:

```
myForm.Controls.Find("panelX1Y2")
```

To suggest a better method, don't use strings for something like this. It is hackish and sloppy.

**Instead, initialize your panels in a 2D array and use the array indices to find the right panel.**

Comment: Yeah i just found a almost simular solution: this.Controls[newpanel].BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
ill try this with the 2d array too ...

Answer (score -1):

Could you not use a dictionary? Remember that a dictionary isn't ordered if this is important to you.

```
 Dictionary<string, Panel> dcPanels = new Dictionary<string, Panel>();
 dcPanels.Add("GridA", new Panel());
 Panel p = dcPanels["GridA"];
```

Comment: woulnd be a 2d array enough and easier? because ive never worked with a dictionary..