# Using one Windows Form - Visual Studios c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am making a Multiple Choice test application using Windows Forms on Visual Studios. When a user answer one question, they will click next to proceed to the next question. Would I be able to use a single windows frame to display all my questions? When I do it on more then one windows form I had to do `this.Hide()` and then `.Show()` the other form. I don't have a problem with doing this but when it hide and shows the other windows form it isn't open on exact same position, it keeps moving.

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for a Wizard-style interface. I sill recommend this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033954/make-a-wizard-like-application-in-winforms

Comment: @DavidStratton I am a little confused here, do you have to download the wizard to show at the tools?

Comment: Why don't you just change the Text property of the Label and RadioButtons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a UserControl that displays the question and the multiple choice answers. When the user clicks the Next button, you remove the UserControl from your form's Controls collection, create a new instance of your custom UserControl with the next question's details on it, and then add the new instance to your form's Controls collections. This structure will let you do the app on a single Form.

Comment: If you use this approach be aware that controls may rely on Dispose being called to clean up resources and if you remove them from the controls collection you will need to do this manually as it will not be done when Dispose is called on the Form.

Comment: Is there any tutorial on how to use this method? I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wizard.

Here you have two links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18674/A-Simple-Wizard-Control-for-Net-2-0-with-Full-Desi

Add this library to Toolbox:

1. Right click on the Toolbox and select "Add Tab" from the context menu.
2. Specify name for the newly created tab, such as "Wizard".
3. Activate the tab, right click on it and select "Choose Items..." for the context menu.
4. Now browse to the folder where is assembly "WizardBase.dll" and select it.

http://winformswizard.codeplex.com/

Comment: I am a little confused here, do you have to download the wizard?

Comment: I have downloaded the library and put it in my reference folder but it is not showing in my toolbox? Any idea why?

Comment: @user1781232 I added you short description how you can do this.

Comment: I tried it but it seems like you don't have a full control on how you want to design it. I cannot add radio button etc.

Comment: @user1781232 you can do this. You must choose option "Add Custom Step" from Wizard SmartTag and you can Drag&Drop everything you want from Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

I would better suggest you to use Panel form the tool box for multiple forms. It would be better for the multiple choice questions.

Then for every panel use property visible set to either True or false depending on which panel you want to navigate.

See this to understand more in detail
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDOXzz_0gYE&feature=related

Comment: Good Idea, but tricky at the same time if you want to come back to make some changes to a specific panel as they are layered over each other, isn't it?

Comment: Whenever you are making a panel double click at that time and open in a code, give a proper name.. It will become easy for you to track every panel

Comment: use this link, you will understand how to track the panels

Comment: the link is  <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401548/get-panel-at-specific-positions-in-c-sharp>

Answer (score 0):

The simpler the better.
The simplest way is to make a panel, (in one window), and then add labels with your question and all options of the answer in that panel. Then on the click on the NEXT button, change the texts of all the labels at once.

As far as your problem of opening different windows on the same position on the screen, change the **DefaultPosition** property of all the forms to CenterScreen or CenterParent.

Comment: Using different forms for each question would make the application redundant and bulky. Try doing it in the same form (one window).